# Random websites not display on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This code is generating a random link from variable but that link is not opening in `iframe` I need to display random links in `iframe` whenever the button is clicked. How to do that?

```
<html>

<script>

var cat1 = [
    "http://arborjs.org",
    "http://cartodb.com",
    "http://vis4.net/labs/185"
    ];

var myFrame = document.getElementById("frame");
getRandomUrl(myFrame);

function getRandomUrl(myFrame) {
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*cat1.length);
   var url = cat1[index];
   document.getElementById('frame').src = url;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

   getRandomUrl(myFrame); 

});
</script>
<body>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<br>
<iframe id="frame" src="" style="width:500px; height: 500px"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the script tag after all your HTML or wait for the window to load.

Also, you're calling a function before it's defined.

`This code is generating a random link from variable`

I don't think this is happening, if you open your console it should tell you the function and iframe are both undefined, as I stated above.